# Remove 'zoom to' tool in pop up feature information ArcGIS API for JS, or define the number of clicks i.e. defined scale

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How can I remove at all 'zoom to' tool in the pop up attribute information? Or how can I define the scale (number of clicks) in case if the 'zoom to' can not be removed.

I have particular layers which are defined to be visible till 1:3200, after this scale the features are not visible (with scrolling). The problem is as follow:

-The layer  has attribute information, but the 'zoom to' button it makes me problem, because it zooms to the location of the feature (eventhough the feature it dissappears), it zooms till 1:500.

In short how I can remove the 'zoom to' button at all, or define the scale when clicking the button?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to hide the "Zoom To" link:

```
div.esriPopupWrapper .zoomTo {
  display: none;
}
```

Or set a minScale on your map to limit how far you can zoom in on the map.

```
map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "topo",  
  center: [-122.45, 37.75], 
  zoom: 5,
  maxScale: 15000000
});
```

Here's a jsbin showing both:  http://jsbin.com/qahahi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that the first option is better. The second one it appears to all layers on the map. I wanted to apply this just to one layer.

Comment: For 4.20, `.esri-popup__footer {
  display: none !important;
}` worked.

Comment: Hiding with css doesn't appear to be feasible in v4 if a) you are using custom actions and/or b) the _zoom to_ button is hidden behind an ellipsis. See @jeffreinhart's answer for the proper js way of hiding the _zoom to_ button.

Answer (score 2):

Since 4.0, you can turn the zoom-to action off this way... after declaring the MapView:

```
view = new MapView ({<your params>});
```

Set default actions for the popup viewModel to false:

```
view.popup.viewModel.includeDefaultActions = false;
```

This was a little counter-intuitive for me... I was trying to set the actions on a popupTemplate for a FeatureLayer, so I assumed includeDefaultActions would be set on that object. Once I understood that a popup and a popupTemplate are properties of the MapView object, this made sense.

Very useful if you want to include your own action in place of the default zoom-to action. Again, this gets to be counter-intuitive since adding your own [action](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#actions) for a [popupTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html) is done as a property of a [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html) or more generally a [Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-Layer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Except for the simple solution I explained below, unfortunately none of the solutions I've found online worked for me to remove the "Zoom To" option from the default popup.

**Solution:** You simply need to remove the "Zoom To" action from the ["actions" array](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#actions). Emptying the array completely worked for me since I haven't added any additional actions to this array (by default, the array only contains one action: "Zoom To")

In JavaScript, there are [many different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046) to delete all elements of an array. What I personally did was:

```
view.popup.actions = [];
```

Above, "view" denotes the SceneView instance I created. This "view" instance might have a different name (and not necessarily has to be a SceneView) in your code but the rest should be the same...

**Tip:** you can always check the contents of your "actions" array by logging its contents in the console using:

```
var count=0;
view.popup.actions.forEach(element => {
  console.log("Item " + count + " : " + element.id );
  count++;
});
```

For more details, [click here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#actions) to check out the official documentation of actions in popup.

Comment: At 4.20, actions are defined as null. So, this method didn't work for me.